# Unpacking a list in python using .T?

Tags: python, list, numpy, scipy

I'm using scipy's method integrate.odeint to solve a second order LDE. The method requires that the equation be put in the form of a system of two first-order equations in two unknowns. The method

```
odeint(system_matrix,initial_conditions_matrix,time_values)
```

outputs the solution vector at each point of time in time_values. The solution vector is actually of the form [u,u'], where u is the variable I am interested in. So I want to plot only u. I found online one way of accomplishing this is to use

```
u,u'=odeint(system_matrix,initial_conditions_matrix,time_values).T
```

but I don't understand why this works and what does the .T at the end mean?

Comment: it means "transposed"

Comment: Have you tried the column indexing demonstrated in the `odeint`  docs? `sol[:,0]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`odeint(system_matrix,initial_conditions_matrix,time_values)` is a matrix of 2 columns.

To be able to get the first column, first use `.T` (transpose) and then you are able to unpack since the elements are oriented like you want.

BTW I doubt that `u'` is a valid variable name. I would do:

```
u,_ = odeint(system_matrix,initial_conditions_matrix,time_values).T
```

since second value is of no interest to you.

Comment: Add that `unpack` iterates on the first dimension of an array.

Comment: @hpaulj could you elaborate? And your `[:,0]` thing sounds even better, would allow to avoid transposition right?

Answer (score 0):

The example I have in mind is:

```
>>> sol = odeint(pend, y0, t, args=(b, c))
The solution is an array with shape (101, 2). The first column is theta(t), and the second is omega(t). The following code plots both components.

>>>
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.plot(t, sol[:, 0], 'b', label='theta(t)')
>>> plt.plot(t, sol[:, 1], 'g', label='omega(t)')
```

`sol[:,0]` selects the first column of `sol`

Unpacking is usually used with a function that returns a tuple, for example:

```
def foo():
   ....
   return [1,2,3],{3:3}
x, y = foo()
```

should end up with `x` being a list, `y` a dictionary.

But it works with any iterable, provide the number of terms match.  For example a 2 row array can be unpacked into 2 arrays.

```
In [1]: x, y = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
In [4]: x,y
Out[4]: (array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5]))
```

If I'd created a (3,2) array I would have needed `x,y,z= ...`, or `.T`.

Because we can index columns and rows, unpacking isn't used a lot in `numpy`.  Usually we have too many rows to unpack.  But it works just as basic Python intended to.

As a matter of curiosity, `transpose` works on a tuple

```
In [6]: np.transpose((x,y))
Out[6]: 
array([[0, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 5]])
```

This is actually used in `np.argwhere`, which turns the tuple of indices produced by `np.where` into array with the same number of columns as dimensions.